# What is the init function of a dynamic module in python?

Tags: python, c, dll, ctype

I am getting the same error of these other two questions:
[ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function, but it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041861/importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-but-it-does)
 and 
[Cython compiled C extension: ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024805/cython-compiled-c-extension-importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-fu)

But their solutions are not equal, and didn't work for me as well.

I am trying  to call functions of a shared library that I have wrote in c,  inside my python program.

I compiled my  shared lib like this:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,playfaircrack.so -o playfaircrack.so -fPIC playfaircrack.c scoreText.o
```

I created a module, and inside this module I  load this lib with:

```
cracker = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./playfaircrack.so')
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "playfair.py", line 2, in <module>
    import playfaircrack
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initplayfaircrack)
```

Which is very strange, because if I run  the python interpreteer, and call directly:

```
cracker = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./playfaircrack.so')
```

I can access the functions of my shared lib.

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the line

```
import playfaircrack
```

in `playfair.py` and it should work.

Alternatively, rename `playfaircrack.so` to something else or moved it to a different directory.
Python gets confused if you have two files with the same module name, i.e.
`playfaircrack.py` and `playfaircrack.so` in the same directory. Python tries to import `playfaircrack.so`, which is no valid Python module, before it gets to `playfaircrack.py`.

Comment: Well. I just can't do that because playfair is the main program, and playfaircrack is a module called from the main program.

Comment: Never occurred something like this to me. It worked. Thank you :)